# sinon js assertion error after node is updated

Tags: node.js, sinon

After updating Node to 8.1.4 , Sinon started giving unexpected assertion error.
The first line does not work here

```
expect(spy).to.have.been.calledWith({type:'RECEIVE_INFO', status:'InProgress'})

expect(spy).to.have.been.calledWith({type : 'REQUEST_INFO'})
```

Here the line one does not work for some reason. But the line 2 works. All , the other dependent code is same. The same code works when we use node 7. Please help. Please let me know in case of any questions.

Comment: Probably a transcription issue, but line 2 has a typo...

Comment: Please ignore the typo. Can you elaborate more on transcription issue?

Comment: I meant you probably made the typo while entering the question.

Comment: Typo is corrected. Not sure Node version 8.1.4 causes assertion error. But if we use Node 7 or below same code works without any issues.

Comment: I assume you're using the latest sinon.js?  7.1.1?

Comment: Can you also show us what the spy function definition is?